# setting python path environment variable for tensorflow models in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, environment-variables

I am following [TensorFlow Models version 1.11](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/v1.11/official) to add the path to models to my `PYTHONPATH`.

I wrote in the end of `~/.bashrc` the following command:

```
# setting PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/yij8/Documents/notchange/models"
```

where `/home/yij8/Documents/notchange/models` is the path to my models folder.

However after I restarted the terminal, and typed in

```
pip3 install --user -r official/requirements.txt
```

it showed

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'official/requirements.txt'
```

which made me really confused.

I checked the python path by `echo $PYTHONPATH`, it showed

```
:/home/yij8/Documents/notchange/models
```

Could anyone tell me where I did wrong?

Thanks